# how to get the height of a div with overflow:auto property set in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a parent div with overflow:auto and max-height:400px. It has a list of inner div with content in it. How can I get the height of the entire parent div.

I have used couple of methods but none of them is working for me.

I am not able to figure what I am to doing wrong. Any help would be appreciable.

```
$('.outer').height();
$('.outer').scrollHeight;
$('.outer').outerHeight(true);
```

Here is my fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/14qv800n/

Comment: don't you mean the height + the total posible scroll?

Comment: I want the total height of the .outer div

Comment: That is exactly what I want @Vandervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code gets the visible height of the element - in this case `200` pixels. Assuming you want to get the total height of the scrollable content you need to get the `scrollHeight` property from the DOMElement within the jQuery object itself. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var h = $('.outer').height();
    var sh = $('.outer')[0].scrollHeight;
    console.log(h);  // 200
    console.log(sh); // 630 (may change in each browser due to text rendering differences)
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/14qv800n/1/)

Comment: In this fiddle However this is working fine but when I use it my jquery file It return 0.

Comment: Now its working fine. there was some bug in my code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it -

```
alert($(".outer")[0].scrollHeight);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/14qv800n/2/